# Axios sending network error while status is 200 ok

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs2, axios

I'm sending a picture on my node.js express server with this axios query:

```
axios.post(this.server + 'images',
    formData, {
        crossdomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The picture is now on the server, but ,please have a look at this strange behavior i'm seeing inside of the firefox console , it says 'network error', while Axios is receiving a 200 status !:

[image: problem]

```
POST http://localhost/images
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 20ms]

Error: "Network Error"
    createError createError.js:16
    handleError xhr.js:81
```

This is my node.js backend Cors params  :

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(
  require("cors")({
    origin: function(origin, callback) {
      callback(null, origin);
    }
  })
);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  //to allow cross domain requests to send cookie information.
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  // list of methods that are supported by the server
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");

  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, X-XSRF-TOKEN"
  );

  next();
});
```

This a big problem, because I need to be able to Exploit the.then() response, and i can't .

What else should I do ?

- My **node server** is started on **localhost:80**
- And my **Webpack-vue.js app** is started on **localhost:8080**

*Note :* 
This is my node function for getting pictures, Please notice that I'm sending a 200 status after the picture gets uploaded :

```
app.post("/images", upload.single("file"), function(req, res, next) {
sharp(req.file.path)
    .resize(200, 200)
    .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
      fs.writeFile(req.file.path, buffer, function(e) {});
    });

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

**EDIT** Changed my node server port to 3000 : 
The problems remains the same :

```
POST http://localhost:3000/images
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 11ms]

Error: "Network Error"
    createError createError.js:16
    handleError xhr.js:81
```

How can I get the result answer ?

I need to get the renamed picture, and can't reach the .then() axios function.

Please have look there :
[image]

I'm not able to get the nico.jpg-5454545 inside the axios .then() , it always says 'network error'

**EDIT  3 :** 
Changed my backend params like that with no luck : ( this is the webpack app port)

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081");
```

**EDIT 4 :** 
Changed my axios query like this with no luck ( This is the node.js server port) :

```
axios.post(this.server + 'images',
                    formData, {
                      crossdomain: true,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "http://localhost:3000"
                        }
                    }
                ).then(function (e) {
                     if (e){
                    console.log(e);
                   }
                })
               .catch(function (err ) {
                   if (err.message === "Network Error"){
                    console.log(err); // Works but nothing gets shown
                   }

                }); 
        },
```

**EDIT 5 :**

Tried this code with no luck, I need to access the response data, and only gets ' NETWORK ERROR'

```
 const send = async () => {
            try {
                return await  axios.post(this.server + 'images',
                    formData, {
                      crossdomain: true,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    }
                )
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
            }

            const myFilename = send()
            console.log(myFilename);
```

[image]

I'm trying to switch to vue-resource, I really have enough !

**Edit 6 :** it seems like it is still a CORS issue :

[image]

**EDIT 7 : RESOLVED  !!!**

The problem was that my whole CORS code **was under my app.post("/images" ... function** inside of my app.js on the node.js server . In other words, the cors code needs to stay at the top of the app.js node.js server file.

This is my CORS code now , please notice, it is now BEFORE the images web service :

```
// ----------------------------------- CORS -------------------------------------------

const cors = require("cors");
app.use(require("cors")());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:8081/images"],
    credentials: true
  })
);

// ----------------------------------- END OF CORS -------------------------------------------

app.post("/images", upload.single("file"), function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file);

  sharp(req.file.path)
    .resize(200, 200)
    .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
      fs.writeFile(req.file.path, buffer, function(e) {});
    });
  res.send({ filename: req.file.filename });
  // res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

it is working flawless now , No network error no more and i'm getting my filename properly!! 
[image]

Comment: Try a different port on your localhost, 3000 or 8000. I'm pretty sure your localhost won't let you connect to port 80

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Ok, I will try this out

Comment: If that works for you I would recommend setting your port value to `process.env.PORT || 3000`. Some hosting providers will set the `PORT` environmental variable

Comment: Hello, Changed my node server port to 3000, it is still not working

Comment: what is the value of `req.file.path`? this error is from axios (google it your find others), but I think the issue is serverside, you know your writing back to the file, maybe sharp has a lock on it (your not handing `err` or `e`, so try looking there). Why is it returning the filename when your not sending it? please show the rest of your code.

Comment: also whats with the multiple `require("cors")`, not that it matters

Comment: No matter as long as I return the filename, or just a 200 status with res.sendStatus(200);, I'm getting the same 'network error' error, So I can't access the .then() response at all, I'm totally bloqued.

Comment: Thank you, I have removed all of the SHARP code, leaving only a send 200 status but the axios network error still remains.

Comment: Can somebody help me ? I can't get the response data while it appears in the console, is axios bugged ? Where to find another http lib ?

Comment: Im now returning   res.send({ filename: req.file.filename }); , the status is 200 , and I can see it inside of the console, but cant access to the..then() function from axios, it always says 'netwok error', while there is NO network error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT 7 : RESOLVED  !!!**

The problem was that my entire CORS code **was written under my app.post("/images" ... function** inside of my app.js on the node.js server . In other words, the cors code needs to stay at the top of the app.js node.js server file.

This is my CORS code now , please notice, it is now BEFORE the images web service :

```
// ----------------------------------- CORS -------------------------------------------

const cors = require("cors");
app.use(require("cors")());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:8081/images"],
    credentials: true
  })
);

// ----------------------------------- END OF CORS -------------------------------------------

app.post("/images", upload.single("file"), function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file);

  sharp(req.file.path)
    .resize(200, 200)
    .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
      fs.writeFile(req.file.path, buffer, function(e) {});
    });
  res.send({ filename: req.file.filename });
  // res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

it is working flawless now , No network error any more, and i'm getting my filename properly!! 
[image]