# Localhost to EC2, GET request works but POST request not working AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I created a node js app with an express server, after that, I dockerize it and deployed it on AWS ECS, one EC2 instance is also running with good health and in the security group, all traffic is allowed in inbound rules. I have one issue I am sending requests from the frontend to the backend only the GET request works but when I am trying a POST request it didn't work. Below is a screenshot of the Axios error I got when I POST the request -:
[image]

I also added a CORS header in the node js backend app -:
[image]

Where is the issue can someone guide me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn’t look like EC2 issue but mostly your code.

Please have a look at this: [Axios sending network error while status is 200 ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717673/axios-sending-network-error-while-status-is-200-ok)